# In Rails, how do you have multiple versions of puma-dev running on different versions of Ruby via ruby-install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, puma-dev, ruby-install

I have many different Rails apps using `puma-dev`.

I have started a new Rails app using Ruby 3+ which works great on localhost, however when I visit the site via `puma-dev` I get an error. This is because I think `puma-dev` is using the wrong version of Ruby to start the app.

The puma dev logs show this error:

```
! Unable to load application: Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 2.6.6, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.2
/Users/abc/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/bundler-2.2.28/lib/bundler/definition.rb:441:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.6.6, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

I’m using `ruby-install` and `chruby` to select differernt Rubies.

How do I go about making `puma-dev` use the versions of ruby installed via `ruby-install` so that all my different apps can use differnt versions of Ruby?

Comment: What is the default shell that you use? Bash, Zsh?

Comment: Are you using a `.ruby-version` file in your Rails folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems puma-dev is not fully compatible with chruby in all situations. But this can be fixed by creating a `.pumaenv` file in your Rails project folder:

```
# Load chruby
source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh

# Change to your desired Ruby version
chruby ruby-3.1.2
```

Please adjust according to where your `chruby.sh` file is installed on your system.

If you want to make the setup compatible with `.ruby-version` files, you could do this instead:

```
source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
chruby $(cat .ruby-version)
```

For further discussion on this topic see this puma-dev issue:
https://github.com/puma/puma-dev/issues/53

Comment: That's great thank you so much! Can I ask how you tracked it down please, in the pursuit of teaching, I had a good google of the issue and couldn't find this solution.

Comment: Thank U. My first task was to understand what puma-dev is. I never heard of it, and it took quite a while to figure out what it actually does. I made a note of it as some sort of Rails/Rack launcher front-end. Next task was to figure out HOW it does what it does, as it seemed like a slightly magic tool that "just works", but not really explained how. I think I googled puma-dev and bundler, and came upon an issue that showed exactly the source code line that launches everything in puma-dev. This was tremendous help, and direct answer to the "how" question. It runs `bundle exec` using `bash -c`.

Comment: At this point I suspected your issue as some sort of failure to load the environment based on a different shell setup, because of their use of Bash. It turns out this is partially true, but perhaps not the full explanation. I find out you could use these dot files to adjust the env. Interesting. Progress. Finally I think I just put chruby into their issue tracker for the sake of seeing if such a search would producce any results, and this issue came up, putting the final puzzle pieces in place. A bit of luck which sped up the solution.

Comment: So lesson for myself also: try the issue tracker first before anything else :)